# Xcode build for environment

Tags: ios, xcode, environment-variables

Currently working on an iPhone app that connects to several different webservices. These webservices have several different addresses depending on the environment we're connecting to:

- Testing - http://staging.example.com/api/testing/servicename
- Staging - http://staging.example.com/api/servicename
- Production - http://www.example.com/api/servicename

I'd like to know what the best convention is for defining these urls and switching between them depending on what environment we want to build for. Is this something I can define in my build settings or can I set up various builds using a define to specify the environment?

Note: Not sure if it matters but for the moment we're using purely Objective-c although we may integrate Swift sometime much later in the project's lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me:

```
#ifdef TARGET_PROD
    #define BASE_URL @" http://www.example.com/api/"
#endif
#ifdef TARGET_VAL
    #define BASE_URL @"http://staging.example.com/api/"
#endif

#ifdef TARGET_TEST
    #define BASE_URL @"http://staging.example.com/api/testing/"
#endif
```

Put this, for example, in Commons.h or a common project file.

And for any Target go to Build Settings and set Processor Macros adding TARGET_PROD in "Debug" and "Release", TARGET_TEST for target test and TARGET_VAL for target staging. 
When you make a request simply append at your BASE_URL the SERVICENAME like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", BASE_URL,yourService]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSUserDefaults`.

For example, set the production value as the fail over default by passing it in a dictionary to `-registerDefaults:`. This puts the value in the `NSRegistrationDomain`. Then for your validation and testing you could:

- Set the value in the `NSArgumentDomain` using code. This would override the value in the `NSRegistrationDomain`.
- Pass the value as a launch argument. When you do this, the value is inserted into the `NSArgumentDomain`, again overriding any value in the `NSRegistrationDomain`.

`NSUserDefaults` searches the domains in a specific order to find a value. This behavior is explained well in [this post by oleb](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/nsuserdefaults-handling-default-values/).

This approach is flexible, and does not have some of the disadvantages of using conditional compilation to solve this problem.